# Aem 6.1 login with json response

Tags: java, json, servlets, aem, sling

I try to write an easy servlet for Login classic cq Users. The j_security_check method is good, but I need an json response for the error handling.

What is the easiest way? 
I found realy complicated solutions which doesnt work. 
 --> http://www.wemblog.com/2013/03/how-to-create-custom-authentication.html

Is there not an simple way to change the j_security_check response to json response?

Or maybe just call login method (with username, password) from the SlingAllMethodServlet?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could adapt the login mask provided by the geometrixx example?
The documentation on identity management describes the registration and login forms, profile pages and more:
https://docs.adobe.com/docs/en/cq/5-6-1/administering/identity_management.html